# A Framework for MVC and NHibernate

Tags: frameworks, s#arp-architecture

I was currently looking at S#arp Architecture. It seems to be still too young to develop anything on top of it.

Is there any alternative to S#arp that include support for NHibernate (fluent a plus), testing and MVC?

Comment: I would be interested to know why do you think that way?

Comment: I'm curious if your opinion has changed in the last few months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice you to just pick up ASP.NET MVC and use fluent nhibernate as your repository. Though Sharp architecture is pretty cool as well.

Comment: Could you say why you would recommend this approach over using somethin like sharp?